# Accessing a users contacts from a webpage

Tags: qr-code

Is it possible to access a mobile users phone contacts from a web page?  The company I work for would like to use QR codes to direct people to a coupon on their website and then give viewers the option of sending the url to their friends in a text message.

Obviously this would be an opt in service. Perhaps you would need to build a mobile application to accomplish the task?  If anyone has an idea on how to accomplish this or something similar please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is not possible to access the contact database via a web page, on any of the major platforms; in order to access this data, a native application is required.

Comment: That makes the most sense to me. I thought there might be an option that I wasn't aware of.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nate is right.

The only thing that you can do (that won't accomplish everything you need) is encode SMS message in QR code (e.g. "sms:number:subject" see http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/BarcodeContents), this way your company will get user's phone number as part of SMS message, but not numbers of his/her friends.

Answer (score 0):

An [API for accessing contacts](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebAPI/ContactsAPI) is being built into the [WebApi](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebAPI/ContactsAPI) by Mozilla but as of today it's not enabled by default and I expect cross browser support is still far off.